# i want to get a specific link, but getting error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Tags: python

i want to get the specific link, i know my variable data2 has some errors...
and i'm not sure is this line of code used correctly or not either : "print(data2.strip())"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnokh.png)

```
import requests as rq
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


PATH = "C:/Users/user/OneDrive/desk/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://lcsc.com/")

search1 = driver.find_element_by_id("input-25")


keyword =[ "C79342",
           "C193222",
"C147294",
"C84408",
"C2924"]

for i in keyword:
    search1.send_keys(i)
    search1.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/button')
    button.click()
    time.sleep(20)
    soup1 = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    data1 =soup1.find(class_= "head").get_text()
    data2 =soup1.find(link_= "data-n-head").get_text()
    print(data1)
    print(data2.strip())
    
            
    search1.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL+"a")
    search1.send_keys(Keys.DELETE)
```

the code on the web page is :
link data-n-head="ssr" rel="canonical" href="https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Multilayer-Ceramic-Capacitors-MLCC-SMD-SMT_YAGEO-CC0402KRX7R7BB104_C60474.html"

i want to get the href in the link...
can anyone help me to correct? thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use API for this

```
import requests


def get_stock(code):
    url = f"https://wwwapi.lcsc.com/v1/products/detail?product_code={code}"
    headers = {
        'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
    }

    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

    return response.json()['stockNumber']


keyword =["C79342", "C193222", "C147294", "C84408", "C2924"]
for key in keyword:
    print(get_stock(key))
```

OUTPUT:

```
601
60820
7250
5605
63
```